# Swift sprite as button toggleable

Tags: swift, button, sprite-kit

I am having trouble getting a standard sprite to have a toggle ability using Sprite Kit. I don't want to use UIButton.

I tried linking code in override func touchesBegan, but I am stumped. I am not used to swift at all and buttons with spritekit are proving to be super difficult.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if (!isEnabled) {
            return
        }
        isSelected = true
        if (targetTouchDown != nil && targetTouchDown!.respondsToSelector(actionTouchDown!)) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(actionTouchDown!, to: targetTouchDown, from: self, forEvent: nil)
        }
    }
```

I want to tap on a sprite and have it change colors and send data to two different arrays. I have experience with arrays with other languages so I don't need help there, just with accepting a tap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warner create a subclass and make that touchable.

```
import SpriteKit

protocol touchMe: NSObjectProtocol {
    func spriteTouched(box: TouchableSprite)
}

class TouchableSprite: SKSpriteNode {
weak var delegate: touchMe!

override init(texture: SKTexture?, color: UIColor, size: CGSize) {
    super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:)has not been implemented")
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    delegate.spriteTouched(box: self)
}
}
```

And call it within your code with ...

```
let restart = TouchableSprite(imageNamed: "mine")
restart.delegate = self
```

You need to make your class confirm to the touchMe protocol and add the required method to confirm to it.

```
class ViewController, touchMe
```

Required method.

```
func spriteTouched(box: TouchableSprite) {
    print("sprite touched")
}
```

Comment: thank you for you response! I feel like I'm flailing through swift lol.

   I am getting an error on restart.delegate = self ... it says "expected declaration" even though it is right below the declaration you provided. 
 Also with restart, is it being used to make the toggle effect possible? I'm assuming it gets called on a second touch, right?

Comment: The delegate variable is declared in the Touchable sprite class? Check it there?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `touchesBegan()` (and there's no reason not to) then you need to realise that this fires whenever the screen is touched. So what you then have to do is to get the location (the coordinates) of the touch and see if there is a sprite there:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        let touchedSprite = selectNodeForTouch(touch.location(in: self))

        if let sprite= touchedSprite {
           sprite.changeColour()
           sprite.sendData(to: array1)
           sprite.senddata(to: array2)
        }
    }
}

// Returns the sprite where the user touched the screen or nil if no sprite there
func selectNodeForTouch(_ touchLocation: CGPoint) -> SKSpriteNode? {
    let touchedNode = self.atPoint(touchLocation) // Get the node at the touch point
    return (touchedNode is SKSpriteNode) ? (touchedNode as! SKSpriteNode) : nil
}
```

So we look at the touch location, get the node at that location and if the node is an SKSpriteNode, we run our `changeColour()` and `sendData()` functions on it.